# fido_dev_make_cred returns success but attstmt and authdata are null

Tags: macos, rust, webauthn, fido, fido-u2f

Trying to perform registration using my YubiKey 5C Nano device.
I have a YubiKey 5C Nano device with PIN set. Product details - YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID.

I tried to use `fido_dev_make_cred(device, cred, pin)`, this returns a `FIDO_ERR_SUCCESS` but the attstmt and authdata are null. AFAIK, this device requires a touch to generate credentials, however, the UV support is FALSE and when `fido_dev_make_cred` is called, it bypasses the wait for touch and returns SUCCESS.

```
libfido2::fido_dev_open(device, libfido2::fido_dev_info_path(di));

        let cred = libfido2::fido_cred_new();

        libfido2::fido_cred_set_type(cred, alg);

        libfido2::fido_cred_set_clientdata(
            cred,
            client_data_json.as_ptr() as *const u8,
            client_data_json.len(),
        );
        

        libfido2::fido_cred_set_rp(cred, rp_id.as_ptr(), rp_name.as_ptr());

libfido2::fido_cred_set_user(
            cred,
            user_id.as_ptr(),
            user_id.len(),
            user_name_c.as_ptr(),
            user_display_name_c.as_ptr(),
            std::ptr::null(),
        );

        libfido2::fido_cred_set_rk(cred, libfido2::fido_opt_t_FIDO_OPT_OMIT);    

        let mut fido_uv = libfido2::fido_opt_t_FIDO_OPT_OMIT;

        let has_pin = libfido2::fido_dev_has_pin(device);

        trace!{"Uv support: {:?}", libfido2::fido_dev_supports_uv(device)}; // false
        trace!{"pin support: {:?}", libfido2::fido_dev_supports_pin(device)}; // true
        trace!{"is fido: {:?}", libfido2::fido_dev_is_fido2(device)}; // true
        
        libfido2::fido_cred_set_uv(cred, fido_uv);

        libfido2::fido_cred_set_extensions(cred, 0);

        let s = String::from("0000");
        let cs = CString::new(s).unwrap();
        let cv: Vec<u8> = cs.into_bytes_with_nul();
        let mut tmp: Vec<i8> = cv.into_iter().map(|c| c as i8).collect::<_>();
        let _cptr: *mut i8 = tmp.as_mut_ptr();

        let r = libfido2::fido_cred_set_pin_minlen(cred, 9);

        if has_pin {
            let r = libfido2::fido_dev_make_cred(device, cred, _cptr);
        } else {
            let r = libfido2::fido_dev_make_cred(device, cred, std::ptr::null() as *const i8);
        }


        libfido2::fido_dev_close(device);
        if r != libfido2::FIDO_OK {
            trace!(
                "fido_dev_make_cred failed {:?}",
                CStr::from_ptr(libfido2::fido_strerr(r))
            );
            libfido2::fido_dev_cancel(device);
        } else {
            trace!("fido_dev_make_cred SUCCESS!");

            let att_len = libfido2::fido_cred_attstmt_len(cred);
            let att_ptr = libfido2::fido_cred_attstmt_ptr(cred);
            let attstmt = std::slice::from_raw_parts(att_ptr, att_len);
            trace!("ATT len={}", att_len);

            let auth_len = libfido2::fido_cred_authdata_len(cred);
            let auth_ptr = libfido2::fido_cred_authdata_ptr(cred);
            let auth = std::slice::from_raw_parts(auth_ptr, auth_len);
            trace!("AUTH len={}", auth_len);

           }
```

If I set the UV to `fido_opt_t_FIDO_OPT_TRUE`, it fails with `UNSUPPORTED` error, but that is because the `fido_dev_supports_uv` returns false.
Why is the touch bypassed and how can I get credentials with a device with PIN.
I am able to get this code to work with a device without PIN (setting the pin to NULL). Is PIN not supported for this device in libfido? What devices are supported with PIN ?

Platform: OSX
Language: libfido2 rust

Thanks.